# Pop up message in case of an empty panel grid EXTJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Hi :) I want to display a popup with a message in the case of a panel grid displayed empty.
i've found some think like

```
 viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true,
        deferEmptyText: false,
        emptyText: 'No data Available'
    },
```

but the message is displayed inside the grid, my need is to disply this message in a popup view.
Any leads ? 
thanks in advance :)

Comment: hey monster, if my answer helped you, please accept it (by clicking on the Checkbox below the downvote).

Comment: i'm testing it write know :) 
I'll let you know ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grid has a [store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-store), and that store has a [load event](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load). [Attach an event listener](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-on) for that event, and check for the number of rows. If zero, use the `Ext.MessageBox` class (e.g the [alert method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox-method-alert)) to pop up the message.